# Layers in canvas fabric.js

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, fabricjs

Can I create layers in canvas¿? I need a layer above objects and other fabric layer with objects that move within that layer. Is it possible?
I use fabric.js

EDIT:
The group does not serve me. I need to create areas within the canvas where I can move objects in them but not the rest. And to know that  position  with respect to that area.
https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/How-fabric-canvas-layering-works

Answer (score 1):

At least for fabric you can group shapes, and will move around as one piece:

```js
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var rect1 = new fabric.Rect({ width: 100, height: 100, fill: '#0bda51' });
var circle = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 100, fill: '#4d5d53' });
var group1 = new fabric.Group([ circle, rect1 ], { left: 100, top: 100 });
canvas.add(group1);

var circle1 = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 100, fill: '#a2add0' });
var circle2 = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 75, fill: '#0038a8' });
var circle3 = new fabric.Circle({ radius: 50, fill: ' #bf94e4' });

var group2 = new fabric.Group([ circle1, circle2, circle3 ], { left: 200, top: 200 });
canvas.add(group2);

var shadow = { color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)', blur: 20, offsetX: 10, offsetY: 10, opacity: 0.6, fillShadow: true, strokeShadow: true }
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ left: 100, top: 100, fill:  "#8ccd7b", stroke: "#000", width: 100,      height: 100, strokeWidth: 10, opacity: .8 });
rect.setShadow(shadow);
canvas.add(rect);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="400" height="400"></canvas>
```

Comment: The group does not serve me. I need to create areas within the canvas where he can move objects in them but not the rest. And knowing that occupy position within that area.

Comment: I will try to help you out, gimme a bit of time

Comment: Thank you. They say the following with respect to the layers: https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/How-fabric-canvas-layering-works
But I am not clear how to get what I asked earlier.

Comment: kangax explain there what is layer order in fabric canvas, I'll try to build a small example with something similar you need.